# Visual Basic 6/Windows 7 Type Mismatch Error

Tags: vb6

I am receiving a type  mismatch error after compiling vb6 
code.

The thing is that only two of the users are receiving the error.  Another user is not.  She is using windowsxp.  We are using windows7.  Any ideas of what could be done to stop seeing this error?   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Error in what  display which

Comment: You will need to be more specific that that.  You have given us no clue what this app references or even what it does.  Does the app log errors?  Can you narrow it down to a particular bit of code.  I'm afraid "My app throws a mismatch error, how do I fix it" isn't enough for anyone to go on. Expand on the problem and you are far more likely to get help solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago i had the same problems with Regional settings on Windows, try to find the Regional settings on the working machine and copy settings to the failing machine/user.